# Node.js require

Tags: node.js, require

I searched and read many articles but could not find a clear answer.
I have a module that exports one simple function that relies on filesystem ('fs') module to check if file exists.

In my 'main' module I also have a function that requires('fs').
Is there a way to use 'fs' from my main module instead of require('fs') in both files?
I thank you in advance

Comment: I wish to know if multiple require of same module would increase memory usage and does it have any impact on the performance. Thanks

Comment: Using require of the same module in each module that it is used is the desired way to code nodejs modules.  It declares dependencies locally.  It makes independently testable and sharable modules.  It promotes reuse.  And, nodejs has been thoroughly optimized so this is efficient and not something you should be trying to optimize away.  There is no added memory cost as the loaded module's exports are shared among all who `require()` or `import` it.  Any execution cost is only at startup, not during runtime. Further, the structure of your code is way more important than any micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't *need* to do this, because `require` is internally optimized and it costs **very close to nothing** to re-import the same module again.  (The cost is literally just checking a cache and returning the same module again.)

But having said that, your function can "require" the `fs` object (or any other object/function/etc. from the `fs` module that it needs) as a parameter when calling the function.  For example:

```
module.exports = function (fs) {
    // use the fs object
}
```

Then in your consuming code...

```
const fs = require('fs');
const myFunc = require('./your_module');

myFunc(fs);
```

Comment: Thank you indeed. That's all I wanted to know :)